# What's the best way to handle unclassified data in a dataset when using a decision tree-based classification model in Python?

Tags: machine-learning, python, classification, feature-extraction

I trained a model that performs classification using decision trees.
I will use my model to perform classification on my dataset.
My dataset also contains data that does not belong to any class in the training data. I don't want to classify them. What should I do?

**training data:**

features: category, product_name, brands

target variable: ingredient

| category | product_name | brands | unit | ingredient |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Turkish Delight | pistachio flavored turkish delight | koska | g | turkish delight |
| Halva, Tahini, Molasses | carob molasses | yeniün | g | molasses |
| Teas | mint lemon tea | naturali | g | herbal and fruit tea bags |
| Package Margarine | classic margarine package | sana | g | margarine |
| Chocolates, Bars, Wafers | 1927 %60 cocoa bitter chocolate | nestlé | g | chocolate tablet |
| Tea Bags for Teapot | yellow label teapot tea 48-pack | lipton | g | herbal and fruit tea bags |
| Fruit Juice | apricot juice | dimes | ml | fruit juice |
| Salt | folic acid sea salt | efsina | g | salt |
| Chocolate Spread, Pastes | cocoa hazelnut paste | sarelle | g | hazelnut paste |
| Tomato Paste | tomato paste in tin | carrefour | g | tomato paste |

Comment: When you say you don't want to classify these samples, do you mean (1) you want to filter them out of your dataset before classifying your test data or (2) you want your classifier to identify that these samples don't belong to any of the possible classes?

Comment: @Lynn I mean that the classifier should not include these examples in any class. (2)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways that I can think of.

The first way is to create a new label called "No class", then move some of the data that shouldn't be classified from your test set to your training set and label them "No class" and retrain your classifier on this extended set.

The second way is, if you can get soft classifications from your classifier (i.e. a number between 0 and 1 for each class that represents the probability or uncertainty that the example belongs to a class), then if all the soft classifications for an example are below some threshold, treat it as unclassified.